# My excel is not showing the system messages it used to display like after removing duplicates X rows were removed

Tags: excel

My excel is not showing messages. For example, when I use "remove duplicates" I used to get a message saying how many records were removed; now, I am not receiving any message after that. All messages are gone from Excel.

What can I do?

I tried enabling alerts using macro but is not working

Comment: You can try reinstalling Office. If that doesn't work then you might try Option 2 in this link - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8

Comment: found answer to my question, check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was the "COM Add-ins"; when you install all at once then it will cause the messages to be gone. I removed them all then installed one by one and is working again.